# How to correctly rearrange arraylist to be able to draw from it

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

After hours of trying i decided to come and ask you guys for help.

I am trying to visualize HPGL Files in Java.

The HPGL file's content looks like this:

```
IN;SP1;PU9360,33;PD9355,31,9352,28,9351,24,9195,43,9042,67,8890,95,8740,128,8592,166,8446,208;PU0,0;SP0;IN;
```

This is just a snippet. The whole files consists of about 30000 characters. i extracted the x and y coordinates via Scanner into an arraylist. I couldn't use an int array as i cannot know what size it will have.

So now i have an arraylist with X Coordinates and another ArrayList with Y-Coordinates.

After that i adjusted the Range of the Coordinates so the final "Picture" can fit on the JPanel.

I used this fantastic Formula i found here on Stack Overflow for the Range adjustement:

```
NewValue = (((OldValue - OldMin) * (NewMax - NewMin)) / (OldMax - OldMin)) + NewMin
```

All the extracted HPGL Coordinates in the ArrayLists are now modified to be "drawable" on the JPanel.

I then used the arraylists to draw lines connecting the "points" and get the hpgl file visualized.

```
while(condition == true){
g.drawLine(Code.sx.get(i), Code.sy.get(i), Code.sx.get(i+1), Code.sy.get(i+1));
i++;
}
```

Well almost everything worked as i expected except for the one Problem i am facing: The Issue is that the visualized Result is vertically flipped and mirrored. In the first picture you can see the current state and in the second picture which i photoshopped (vertically mirroring it) to show you guys what result i wish to have.

Can someone please help me with rearranging the arraylists to get the expected result?

The arraylists look something like this:

ArrayList sx

```
[196, 189, 183, 176, 176, 170, 163, ...]
```

ArrayList sy

```
[473, 478, 483, 487, 487, 491, 494, ...]
```

Both ArrayLists are one Row with about 2000 Integers in it.

I tried reversing the ArrayList but that didn't help

```
for(int i = 0; i < sx.size() / 2; i++)
    {
        int temp = sx.get(i);
        sx.set(i, (sx.get(sx.size() - i - 1)));
        sx.set((sx.size() - i - 1), temp);
    }
```

If you have any Ideas for me, please let me know.

Thank You
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

This is the Current State
[image: This is the Current State]

This is how it should look like
[image: This is how it should look like]

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about HPGL coordinates, but it seems you need to invert y-coordinate (sorry if that's obvious, I can't help with the code further than this)

Comment: I guess the X coordinates are right, but the Y coordinates are flipped, so you should reverse `sy` instead of `sx`.

Comment: In addition to what @Smutje said, you can use the inbuilt [reverse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)) method instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: The point (0,0) in the top left point, the point (xmax, ymax) the bottom right, see there: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/coordinate.html

Comment: I guess StephaneM's comment is on the spot. Too often people think of cartesian coordinate...

Comment: thanks for the input. i tried reversing the y coordinates but the "picture looks horrible. the problem ist that sx and sy are 2 different arraylists. if i reverse sy then i loose the "connection" to sx as the index of both lists was the only bond between both arraylists. hpgl syntax gives you an x,y pair. as i scanned the file at once i was able to split the pair in 2 lists but still knew its gonna be fine as the 1st int in sx pairs to 1st int in sy and so on. after reversing sy only, that connection vanishes. any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calculating your y coordinate as

```
NewValue = NewMax - (((OldValue - OldMin) * (NewMax - NewMin)) / (OldMax - OldMin)).
```

Comment: Thank You redge! Your Suggestion worked perfectly! You' re my Hero of the week :)